# Continuous flow topologically equivalent to a flow of class $C^\infty$

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology, dynamical-systems

I have heard that all continuous flow the projective plane, the Klein bottle and the sphere is topologically equivalent to a flow of class $C^\infty$, but I have not been able to find any reference where I can find a demonstration, someone help me with that please?